# why won't my SQL SUM add for my join?

Tags: sql, select, sum, inner-join

So I have the code where it would sum up all of the vendors payments together and then show it on a descending list.

```
SELECT vendor_name, SUM(payment_total) AS payment_total
FROM Vendors  JOIN Invoices
     ON (Vendors.vendor_id = Invoices.vendor_id)
GROUP BY vendor_name, payment_total
ORDER BY payment_total DESC;
```

However all it does is make a lists of the vendor names duplicated along with the payment total just being listed instead of adding up. I try to use the `DISTINCT` but kept getting the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sum the total per vendor name, not per vendor name and total as your current `group by` clause indicates. Just remove `total_payment` from it and you should be fine:

```
SELECT   vendor_name, SUM(payment_total) AS payment_total
FROM     Vendors 
JOIN     Invoices ON (Vendors.vendor_id = Invoices.vendor_id)
GROUP BY vendor_name
ORDER BY payment_total DESC;
```

Comment: Works fine on [tag:postgres] and [tag:mysql]. Didn't check any closed source databases, but IIRC, ANSI-SQL allows ordering by aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `GROUP BY payment_total` since you want totals grouped by the vendor:

```
SELECT 
    vendor_name, 
    SUM(payment_total) AS payment_total
FROM 
    Vendors  
    JOIN Invoices ON Vendors.vendor_id = Invoices.vendor_id
GROUP BY 
    vendor_name
ORDER BY 
    SUM(payment_total) DESC
```

and Order By `SUM(payment_total) DESC`

Comment: OOOOoooh, so when I placed payment_total in GROUP BY is where I went wrong. THANK!